# How does $\sqrt {\frac{{4 + \sqrt {15} }}{8}} = \frac{{\sqrt {8 + 2\sqrt {15} } }}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have the follow answering to a question from my textbook:
$\sqrt {\frac{{4 + \sqrt {15} }}{8}}$
However my textbook simplifies it to:
$\frac{{\sqrt {8 + 2\sqrt {15} } }}{4}$

I've checked and my answer seems to be the same value as the one in the textbook but How do I go about getting the textbooks answer?

Comment: $$\sqrt{\frac{x}{8}} = \sqrt{\frac{2x}{16}} = \frac{\sqrt{2x}}{4}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, why would the textbook choose to simplify in this way?

Comment: Don't ask me, ask the author. (In other words, I have no idea why.)

Comment: Some like to avoid "radicals in the denominator"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply as follows:

$$\sqrt{\frac{4+\sqrt{15}}{8}\frac{2}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{8+2\sqrt{15}}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{15}}}{4}$$

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{4+\sqrt{15}}8=\frac{8+2\sqrt{15}}{16}$$

which in fact can be further simplified as

$$\frac{(\sqrt3)^2+(\sqrt5)^2+2\sqrt3\sqrt5}{16}=\left(\frac{\sqrt5+\sqrt3}4\right)^2$$

Comment: That's a neat trick!